# No tooltip when hover the mouse over multiline chart

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

I'm using d3 as my charting library and after the graph plot as i hover my mouse i can't see any values at the datapoint but in the HTML console i can see event is getting triggered.

I want to see date and value when i hover but i'm not getting any idea how to proced with it as i'm very new to d3.

below is the small snippet i coded :

```
dataNest.forEach(function (d, i) {
          svgVar.selectAll("path")
    .data(dataNest)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .style("stroke", function () { // Add the colours dynamically
                  return d.color = color(d.key);})
     .on("mouseover",  tooltip)
    .attr("d", function(d) { return pricelineVar(d.values); })
    .attr("fill","none");

  function tooltip(d,i)
  {
                  svgVar.style("left", d3.event.pageX  + "px")
                  .style("top", d3.event.pageY + "px")
                  .style("display", "inline-block")
                  .html(" x:"+ d.date );  
 }
```

If anyone wants to give any suggestion i can paste the full code as well:[image]

**Full code**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import * as d3 from "d3"
import * as d3Scale from 'd3-scale';
import * as d3Shape from 'd3-shape';
import * as d3Array from 'd3-array';
import * as d3Axis from 'd3-axis';

import {timeParse} from "d3-time-format";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-d3graph',
  template: `
    <h2>{{subtitle}}</h2>
  `
})
export class D3graphComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()  storeIntraffic: string;
  @Input() dateForD3: string;
  @Input() peopleInSumStr: string;

  title: string = 'D3.js with Angular 2!';
  subtitle: string = 'Line Chart';
  peopleInSumArr: any[];
  private margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50};
  private width: number;
  private height: number;
  private x: any;
  private y: any;
  private svg: any;
  private priceline: any;
  private line: d3Shape.Line<[number, number]>;
  d3Data: any;
  dashboard_date: any;
  myArray: any[];
  groupName: string;
  data: any;
  constructor() {
    this.margin = { top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 50 },
    this.width = 1300 - this.margin.left - this.margin.right,
    this.height = 800 - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;
  }

  ngOnInit() { }
  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    if (this.storeIntraffic !== undefined && typeof this.storeIntraffic === 'string') {

        this.data = JSON.parse(this.peopleInSumStr);
        this.peopleInSumArr = JSON.parse(this.peopleInSumStr);
        this.dashboard_date = this.dateForD3;
    //   this.dashboard_date = this.dateForD3;
    //   console.log('d3 this.peopleInSumArr', this.peopleInSumStr);
    //   this.peopleInSumArr = JSON.parse(this.peopleInSumStr);
    //   console.log('d3 this.peopleInSumArr jajdjhdhjd', this.peopleInSumArr);
    //   console.log('this.dateForD3', this.dateForD3);
    //   this.storeIntraffic_plot();
        this.initSvg();
        this.initAxis();
        this.drawAxis();
        this.drawLine();


    }
  }
  private initSvg() {
    d3.select("svg").remove();
    this.svg = d3.select("#svgcontainer")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", this.width + this.margin.left + this.margin.right)
        .attr("height", this.height + this.margin.top + this.margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", 
              "translate(" + this.margin.left + "," + this.margin.top + ")")
     .attr("stroke-width", 2);
  }
  private initAxis() {
    // Parse the date / time
    var parseDate = timeParse("%b %Y");


    // Set the ranges
    this.x = d3Scale.scaleTime().range([0, this.width]);
    this.y = d3Scale.scaleLinear().range([this.height, 0]);
  }
  private drawAxis() {
      var X = this.x;
      var Y = this.y;
      // Define the line

      this.priceline = d3Shape.line()
          .x(function (d) { return X(new Date(d.date)); })
          .y(function (d) { return Y(d.peoplesum); });
  }
  private drawLine() {

      var mindate = new Date(this.dashboard_date['startTime']),
          maxdate = new Date(this.dashboard_date['endTime']);
      this.x.domain(d3.extent([mindate, maxdate]));
      // Scale the range of the data
      var svgVar = this.svg;
      var pricelineVar = this.priceline;
      var margin = this.margin;
      var height = this.height;
      this.y.domain([0, d3.max(this.data, function (d) { return d.peoplesum; })]);
      console.log("this.data", this.data);
      // Nest the entries by symbol
      var dataNest = d3.nest()
          .key(function (d) { return d.storeid;})
          .entries(this.data);

      // set the colour scale
      var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

      var legendSpace = this.width / dataNest.length; // spacing for the legend

      // Loop through each symbol / key

     var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").style("display", "none");
    function enableTooltip(d) {
    tooltip.html("x:" + d.date)
        .style("left", d3.event.pageX  + "px")
        .style("top", d3.event.pageY + "px")
        .style("display", null);
}
      dataNest.forEach(function (d, i) {
       svgVar.selectAll("path")
    .data(dataNest)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .on("mouseover", enableTooltip)
    .attr("d", function(d) { return pricelineVar(d.values); })
    .attr("fill", "none");


          // Add the Legend
          svgVar.append("text")
              .attr("x", (legendSpace / 2) + i * legendSpace)  // space legend
              .attr("y", height + (margin.bottom / 2) + 5)
              .attr("class", "legend")    // style the legend
              .style("fill", function () { // Add the colours dynamically
                  return d.color = color(d.key);
              })
              .text(d.key)
              .attr("stroke-width", 3)




      });
      console.log("after", dataNest);
      // Add the X Axis
      this.svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + this.height + ")")
          .call(d3.axisBottom(this.x));

      // Add the Y Axis
      this.svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "axis")
          .call(d3.axisLeft(this.y));

  }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

To get a tootltip during mouseover, first you have to define a tooltip with display as none.

```
var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").style("display", "none");
```

Then during mouseover event enable the tooltip and bind data to show in the tooltip.

```
function enableTooltip(d) {
    tooltip.html("x:" + d.date)
        .style("left", d3.event.pageX  + "px")
        .style("top", d3.event.pageY + "px")
        .style("display", null);
}
```

You dont need forEach to iterate array. d3 data() takes care of that.

```
svgVar.selectAll("path")
    .data(this.data)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .on("mouseover", enableTooltip)
    .attr("d", function(d) { return pricelineVar(d.values); })
    .attr("fill", "none");

svgVar.selectAll("text")
    .data(this.data)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", (legendSpace / 2) + i * legendSpace)
    .attr("y", height + (margin.bottom / 2) + 5)
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .style("fill", function () {
        return d.color = color(d.key);
    })
    .text(d.key)
    .attr("stroke-width", 3);
```

Comment: No it is still coming as blank. I'm editing the question and pasting the full code .

Comment: I didn't know you have used d3.nest(). Try replacing dataNest with this.data in my solution.

Comment: data s coming undefined